# Login only with phone number without password - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-authentication

I'm working in Laravel, So far I created two logins using guard. Now I'm trying to login via Google using socialite. So successful authentication from google, I get a users profile.
        So from that I can get users email Id. Now I want to login via same guard with password.

```
'adminpanel' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'adminusers',
        ],
         'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ]
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
'adminusers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\VendorUser::class,
        ],
    ],
```

So is there is any tricks to make a authentication, I tried a alot.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the handle function of app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Modify and override your login function:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'mobile_no' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{10}/|digits:10',            
    ]);

    $user = User::where('mobile_no', $request->get('mobile_no'))->first();

    // Check Condition Mobile No. Found or Not
    if($request->get('mobile_no') != $user->mobile_no) {
        \Session::put('errors', 'Your mobile number not match in our system..!!');
        return back();
    }        

    \Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

**Add a entry for mobile_no in resources/views/auth/login.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mobile_no') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="mobile_no" class="col-md-4 control-label">Enter Mobile No.</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="mobile_no" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_no" value="{{ old('mobile_no') }}" required autofocus>
       @if ($errors->has('mobile_no'))
            <span class="help-block">
               <strong>{{ $errors->first('mobile_no') }}</strong>
            </span>
       @endif
</div>
</div>
```